# STM32L4 Wakeup from sleep or shutdown via TSC

Tags: touch, stm32, interrupt

I am working on a project with a STM32L462CEU6 powered by battery. In this project we are also using TSC. Now I want STM32 to go in sleep or shutdown mode and wakeup when a touch pad has been touched. So the goal is that TSC measures in background and when a certain threshold has been reached it fires a "wakeup interrupt". Is that even possible? I only found information about intterupts "acquisition completed" or "maxcount reached".

I already searched for this use case but I failed to find useful information. Perhaps, someone can help me with some hints or sites where I can find more information.

Thanks in advance.

Sebastian

Searched in ST forums, datasheets, helps pages, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with looking at *Functionalities depending on the working mode* table in PWR chapter of RM0394, and then *TSC low-power modes* in TSC chapter in RM.

Summary: TSC does not work in Shutdown mode; and in supported modes there's no magic with threshold, you'd need to wake up at every acquisition and compare the result in software.